# GitLab: one group of people for all the projects in group

Tags: permissions, gitlab, user-permissions

I have a set of projects and one group (team) of people working with them. My team is flat so permissions are the same for all the projects. I'd like to set them at a group level.

So I've created a group (of projects) in gitlab with url e.g. `gitlab.com/mygroup`. Projects have urls in it, like `gitlab.com/mygroup/proj1`, `gitlab.com/mygroup/proj2` and so on. I've added people to the group at page `gitlab.com/groups/mygroup/group_members`. But they cannot get access to projects, unless I add them as a project members directly to every project on page `gitlab.com/mygroup/proj1/project_members`. But in this case I have to repeat action for each person and each project.

How can I add all the people to a group once and they share all permission to all projects?

Comment: You are doing this correct according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/groups.html#adding-users-to-a-group. It looks like a bug, what is your GitLab version?

Comment: I use hosted version at gitlab.com and hope it's the freshest one :) BTW how to get precise version? I installed with the instruction, however some interfaces have changed slightly. Users from the group aren't propagated to project automatically.

Comment: Check URL https://your.domain.name/help and there should be ur version

Comment: Thank you - It's GitLab Enterprise Edition 8.15.3-ee fe6cf5a Up to date

Comment: What is a visibility level of projects? If `Private`, try to change it to `Internal`. To `Private` projects "access must be granted explicitly to each user". Maybe that's a reason.

Comment: Group has `Provate` visibilty. But if I change it to `Internal` on hosted gitlab, will ALL registered gitlab users be able to see them? That's definetely not I want :) I looked at a project level, they are `private`, but there's no other options ;(  At "Feature visibility" section all option set to "group members".

Comment: Yes, it will be visible for all logged in users. You don't see any other options except `private`, so you must have `private` group. `Feature visibility` is based on your project visibility. There is one existing workaround which I will describe as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important fact is all projects and group are private.**

As we mentioned in comments, it seems that [rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#projects) of private projects

> Project access must be granted explicitly for each user

is more important [than](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/groups.html#adding-users-to-a-group)

> One of the benefits of putting multiple projects in one group is that
>   you can give a user to access to all projects in the group with one
>   action

In a private group, the only option is private projects, so all users must be **manually** added to projects.

There is one workaround but I don't know if it's very useful:

1. Create internal group
2. Add members
3. Add internal projects (all users are implicitly joining to projects)
4. Change visibility of projects to private
5. Change group visibility to private

Tested on `8.15.4-ee`

Comment: Thank you! I cranked some privacy options on Gitlab and now projects are visible as they should. Newly added projects are visible for the team as well. Looks like it was GL issue, which they resolved by themselves or after parameters tweaking.